# Como guardar um específico id (problema) noutra secção?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu estou a tentar passar 1 problema por resolver para uma secção chamada "resolvido", ou seja, alguém enviou a partir de `forms` o seu problema que está a ter, depois na parte do `admin` tenho os problemas todos que já foram criados e eu quero mandar para outra secção os que já estão resolvidos, ou seja, tenho 2 secções, uma chamada "por resolver" e outra chamada "resolvido", ao clicar num problema abre um `modal` só com informações do próprio problema e dentro do `modal` quero ter um botão que ao clicar passa o tal problema para a secção dos problemas resolvidos. Para fazer um `modal` para cada problema usei javascript do `bootstrap`, mas não sei como dizer que quero apenas arrastar o problema x para a outra secção. Para isso eu criei uma função com `sql` para mudar o estado do problema para "resolvido" e também gravar o nome do administrador que o resolveu. Vou mostrar o código da estrutura do `modal`, do `javascript` e da função.

```
<td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" data-estado="<?php echo $data['estado'];?>" data-nome="<?php echo $data['nome'];?>" data-assunto="<?php echo $data['assunto'];?>" data-msg="<?php echo $data['msg'];?>" data-img="<?php echo $data['img'];?>" class="button1">Analisar</button></td>
```

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button onclick="alerta()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Resolvido</button>
     <?php 
        $estado="Resolvido";
        $id= $data['id'];
        resolvido($estado,$_SESSION['UserNome'],$id);
     ?>
</div>
```

Nesta parte tem um botão, aparece à frente de cada problema esse botão e ao clicar abre o `modal` só com informações do problema x. E no corpo do `modal` tem código `php` para tentar fazer o tal arrastamento.

```
<script>
            $('#dataModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var botao = $(event.relatedTarget) // Botão que faz o modal abrir
                // Extract info from data-* attributes
                var id = botao.data('id')
                var estado = botao.data('estado') 
                var nome =  botao.data('nome')
                var assunto = botao.data('assunto')
                var msg = botao.data('msg')
                var img = botao.data('img')
                var modal = $(this)
                modal.find('.modal-body').html('<div class="container"> <i><h2 class="cor2">Estado ->' + estado + ' </h2><i> <h3 class="cor2">Nome ->'+ nome + '</h3> <h4 class="cor2">' + assunto + ' </h4> <p class="cor2">' + msg + ' </p> <img class="responsive" src="imagens/' + img + '" /> </div>');
            })
</script>
```

Nesta parte tem o script para abrir o `modal` só com as informações do problema x.

```
function resolvido($estado,$admin,$problemaId){
    global $connection;
    //Consulta
    $sql = "UPDATE `contacto` SET `estado` = '$estado', admin = '$admin' WHERE `id` = '$problemaId'";
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}
```

Nesta última parte tem a função que chamei no corpo do `modal`.

Ajudem-me por favor.

Answer (score 0):

É muito simples, você deve criar no seu banco de dados uma coluna chama `status` neste quando o problema for criado, este `status` continuará como `Null`. Quando você clicar no botão que moverá para resolvido, este botão enviará para uma página que fará o Update do `status` de `Null` para `resolvido`. Então em uma secção você lista somente os com `status´`
 = `Null`, os não resolvidos, e em outra os com `status` = `resolvido`.

Comment: O meu problema é como consigo fazer com que ele só mude o status do problema que eu abrir para resolvido para que ele seja movido para outra secção. Não sei onde devo meter o código para que isso aconteça. Eu quero fazer esta operação dentro do modal, só tenho 1 modal para todos os problemas, usei javascript para isso acontecer

Comment: Crie um link para a pagina de update de status onde por parametro seja passado o `id` do problema e na página de update troque o status do problema para `resolvido`.

Comment: Desculpe estar a pedir isto, mas consegue mostrar um exemplo? Ando um bocado confuso com isto, já tentei tanta coisa e ainda não aprendi javascript, se puder ajudar-me agradecia...